# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

within my condition, I'm trying to assign a new value to the variable name, but I'm getting the error below.

After run my code, I'm getting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment`

Do you have idea to fix it?

I do not know why I'm getting this if the variable is global

**My code**

```
import pytest
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker("en_US")

name = fake.name()

def create_contributor_minimum_requirements(driver):

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn--primary").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='first-name']/input")))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='first-name']/input").send_keys(contributor_name)
    assert driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".actions-bar__nav-link.router-link-active").text == name
    time.sleep(3)

    duplicated_contributor_message = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".field-error-text")

    if duplicated_contributor_message.is_displayed():

        name = fake.name() + fake.name()

        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='first-name']/input").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='first-name']/input").send_keys(name)

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.save-button.btn--disabled-dark.btn--critical").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.save-button.btn--disabled-dark.btn--disabled")))
    assert driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.save-button.btn--disabled-dark.btn--disabled").is_enabled() == False

def search_created_contributor(driver):

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".navbar__menu__item.navbar__menu__item--search").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search__input")))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".search__input").send_keys(name)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search__results__list>li")))

def assert_created_contributor_is_found(driver):

    assert name in driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".search__results__list>li").text

def test_case_one(driver):

    login_to_cms(driver)
    access_contributor_page(driver)
    create_contributor_minimum_requirements(driver)
    search_created_contributor(driver)
    assert_created_contributor_is_found(driver)
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions have their own scope. In order to access a global variable you need to explicitly say so:

```
 def create_contributor_minimum_requirements(driver):
     global name
     ...
```

Hope it helps!